# Android Studio: "App keep stoping" with no errror message

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to practice data binding. Before adding bindings the application was working correctly. Currently, the application turns on for a second and turns off an error appears:

```
 About Me keeping stoping
```

[image]

Same thing when I want to debug the code.

I went through all the code carefully, there are no underscores. Why does the application crash?

Here is the code:
MainActivity.kt

```
package com.pinodev.aboutme
import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager

import com.pinodev.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
            addNickname(it)
        }
    }
    private fun addNickname(view: View){
        binding.apply {
            binding.nicknameText.text = binding.nicknameEdit.text
            invalidateAll()
            binding.nicknameEdit.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.doneButton.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.nicknameText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        // Hide the keyboard.
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pinodev.aboutme"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '31.0.0'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_text"
        style="@style/NameStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nickname_edit"
        style="@style/NameStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/what_is_your_nickname"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="#78909C" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/done" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nickname_text"
        style="@style/NameStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/yellow_star"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bio_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bio_text"
            style="@style/NameStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bio" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Logcat output:

```
2021-09-02 15:09:25.032 4304-4304/com.pinodev.aboutme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pinodev.aboutme, PID: 4304
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pinodev.aboutme/com.pinodev.aboutme.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
        at com.pinodev.aboutme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2021-09-02 15:09:25.049 4304-4304/com.pinodev.aboutme I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4304 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post your [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) output, you will find in there some `Exception`

Comment: `with no error message` yet you've posted your stacktrace?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have posted logcat output. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have not initialized binding yet . You have declared binding at top level to be lateinit and have not initialized yet is what the error is trying to say .

Just make the following changes to your onCreate method , where you initialize your binding and setContentView ,

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
            addNickname(it)
        }
    }
```